# Numpy Matrix Multiplication Broadcast

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an array comprised of N 3x3 arrays (a collection of matrices, although the data type is np.ndarray) and I have an array comprised of N 3x1 arrays (a collection of vectors). What I want to do is multiply each matrix by each vector, so I expect to get back N 3x1 arrays.

Simple example:

```
A = np.ones((6,3,3))
B = np.ones((6,3,1))
np.dot(A,B) # This gives me a 6x3x6x1 array, which is not what I want
np.array(map(np.dot,A,B)) # This gives me exactly what I want, but I don't want to have to rely on map
```

I've tried all kinds of reshaping, explored `einsum`, etc., but can't get this to work the way I want it to. How do I get this to work with numpy broadcasting? This operation will ultimately need to be done many thousands of times, and I don't want `map` or list comprehension operations to slow things down.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to calculate the dot products and create the matrix of the desired shape:

```
np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', A, B)
```

Comment: If it's normal matrix multiplication the signature should be `'ijk,ikl->ijl'`.

Comment: Thank you, @Jaime - have now edited the signature accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

One could use the built-in matrix multiplication in Python 3.5 or above,
introduced in [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/).

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.6

>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.ones((6,3,3))
>>> B = np.ones((6,3,1))
>>> C = A @ B
>>> print(C)
[[[3.]
  [3.]
  [3.]]

 [[3.]
  [3.]
  [3.]]

 [[3.]
  [3.]
  [3.]]

 [[3.]
  [3.]
  [3.]]

 [[3.]
  [3.]
  [3.]]

 [[3.]
  [3.]
  [3.]]]
```

Comment: The `@` operator is exactly the same as the `np.matmul` method, and it should be specified in order to prevent virtual multiplication of terminology and confusion.

Comment: From the PEP 465 early mentioned, one can quote : "For inputs with more than 2 dimensions, we treat the last two dimensions as being the dimensions of the matrices to multiply, and ‘broadcast’ across the other dimensions. " 
This is exactly what one want, thank you Samuel. A question is : is it significantly more efficient that `einsum()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
A = np.random.rand(6, 3, 3)
B = np.random.rand(6, 3, 1)
C = np.array(map(np.dot, A, B))
D = np.sum(A*B.swapaxes(1, 2), axis=2)[..., None]
assert np.allclose(C, D)
assert C.shape == D.shape == (6, 3, 1)
```

The "allclose" is because there's some floating point rounding difference between the two methods on the order of 1e-16.

The .swapaxis and the [..., None] are just to get the arrays to conform to the shapes you specified.  You could also represent it more simply with:

```
A = np.random.rand(6, 3, 3)
B = np.random.rand(6, 3)
C = np.array(map(np.dot, A, B))
D = np.sum(A*B[:, None, :], axis=2)
assert np.allclose(C, D)
assert C.shape == D.shape == (6, 3)
```