# Defining a quadratic function with numpy.meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, linear-algebra, tensor

Let's consider a function of two variables `f(x1, x2)` , where `x1` spans over a vector `v1` and `x2` spans over a vector `v2`.

If `f(x1, x2) = np.exp(x1 + x2)`, we can represent this function in Python as a matrix by means of the command numpy.meshgrid like this:

```
xx, yy = numpy.meshgrid(v1, v2)
M = numpy.exp(xx + yy)
```

This way, `M` is a representation of the function `f` over the cartesian product "`v1` x `v2`", since `M[i,j] = f(v1[i],v2[j])`.

But this works because both sums and exponential work in parallel componentwise. **My question is**:

if my variable is `x = numpy.array([x1, x2])` and `f` is a quadratic function `f(x) = x.T @ np.dot(Q, x)`, where `Q` is a 2x2 matrix, how can I do the same thing with the meshgrid function (i.e. calculating all the values of the function f on "v1 x v2" at once)?

Please let me know if I should include more details!

Comment: `np.exp(x1, x2)`? `numpy.exp(xx + yy)`? Which one?

Comment: Why are you using `meshgrid`, when you can use broadcasting?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo, I even double checked twice! You mean the function numpy.broadcast? I didn't know it: I'm checking it!

Comment: Ok, I read the "broadcasting" documentation page, but I wouldn't know how to exploit it

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. You have a NxN result from `x.T @ Q @ x`. Why do you need meshgrid?

Comment: To help clarify, make a couple of small arrays, say length 4 or 5, or a 2x4 array or so. Make a simple Q, like np.eye(2), and show what operations you want with the expected result. Right now, I'm having a hard time figuring out what your actual question is.

Comment: I am looking for a way to calculate `x.T @ Q @ x` on several inputs `x` at once.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849910/numpy-matrix-multiplication-broadcast

Comment: @rod. Gotcha. Can you make that example then? I'd like to understand better what your inputs and expected outputs look like. If you can show me that, I suspect that I can make an answer for you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I cannot make an example because I don't know how to do it! That is my question ^^

Comment: You absolutely can. Write a line that shows a sample input, and a hand calculated expected output. I understand that you want help vectorizing your operation, but showing the actual results you want for a small toy input will go a long way in making your prose understandable. If you can add a reference implementation using `for` loops, that would remove any remaining ambiguity. As it stands, I still don't have enough information to visualize how you imagine this happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def quad(x, y, q):
    """Return an array A of a shape (len(x), len(y)) with 
    values A[i,j] = [x[i],y[j]] @ q @ [x[i],y[j]]
    x, y: 1d arrays, 
    q: an array of shape (2,2)"""

    from numpy import array, meshgrid, einsum
    a = array(meshgrid(x, y)).transpose()
    return einsum('ijk,kn,ijn->ij', a, q, a)
```

#### Notes

`meshgrid` produces 2 arrays of a shape `(len(y), len(x))`, where first one is with `x` values along the second dimension. If we apply to this pair `np.array` then a 3d array of shape `(2, len(y), len(x))` will be produced. With `transpose` we obtain an array, where an element indexed by `[i,j,k]` is `x[i] if k==0 else y[j]`, where `k` is 0 or 1, i.e. first or second array from `meshgrid`.

With `'ijk,kn,ijn->ij'` we tell `einsum` to return the sum written bellow for each `i, j`:

```
sum(a[i,j,k]*q[k,n]*a[i,j,n] for k in range(2) for n in range(2))
```

Note, that `a[i,j] == [x[i], y[j]]`.

Comment: Does `einsum` exploit nice matrix-multiplication algorithms here?  I really love the `einsum` syntax, but IIRC it's not always the fastest `np` solution if one can use matrix ops.

Comment: @Him I'm not sure if I understand your question. Actually, I don't know what is _nice matrix-multiplication algorithms_ and how to compare them with other solutions. Could you please explain what do you mean? Maybe you have a link to an article about this.

Comment: The way that you learn to multiply matrices "by hand" in school is not very efficient.  Numerical libraries (e.g. `numpy`) all implement better algorithms for matrix multiplication.  AFAIK, this doesn't extend to `einsum` because it is too "flexible" in some sense.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication#Simple_algorithms

Comment: @Him The best alternative I can think of is `(a * np.inner(a, q)).sum(2)`. But on my machine it's much slower then `einsum`. What would you suggest as a replacement for einsum?

Comment: Thanks for your anwer Vitalizzare . I was going to ask what @Him asked. I.e.: is it efficient?

Comment: np.einsum is generally more efficient than regular multiplication